# Issues when specific users data are show in tables?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to show all the users who's status is 0 are showing in the table. With every user data there is a detail button when admin click on this detail all the information about users are show in the form. After watching all the information of user, Admin take action with "VERIFY" OR "REJECTED" user  The issue is when the data is increased in the table the "Verify" &  "Rejected" links are also increased in the form How to solve this issue.

User Data in Table:

[image]

Issue:

[image]

View:

```
<div class="imageGallery" style="height: auto; width: 75%; /*background:grey;*/ margin: 0px auto;">
                    <?php foreach($gallery as $image):?>
                    <div class="image" style=" width:100%; max-width:205px;  display: inline-block;" >
                        <img src="<?php if($image['path'] !=null){ echo base_url()."assets/users/".$image['user_id']."/".$image['path'];}?>" style="width:200px; height:200px; padding:5px; margin-left: 110px  "/>
                    </div>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </div>

                <!--<input type="hidden" name="id" value=?>">-->
                <div class="row" style="padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3" style="margin-left: 344px">
                        <?php foreach($users as $user):?>
                            <a style="text-decoration: none; float: right" href="<?php echo base_url();?>verifyUserEmail/<?php echo $user->email; ?>/<?php echo $user->id; ?>" class="btn btn-link">Verify</a>
                            <a style="text-decoration: none; float: right" href="<?php echo base_url();?>rejectedUser/<?php echo $user->email; ?>/<?php echo $user->id; ?>" class="btn btn-link">Rejected</a>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="float: right;">Update</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Controller:

```
function editUser($id)
    {
        {
            $data["userdetail"] = $this->AdminModel->getUserDetails($id);
            $data["gallery"] = $this->AdminModel->getUserGallery($id);
            $data['users'] = $this->AdminModel->getRoleStatusUsers();


            $this->load->view('Admin/includes/header');
            $this->load->view('User/edituser', $data);
            $this->load->view('Admin/includes/footer');
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
public function userEdit($id, $data){

        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $result = $this->db->update('mh_users', $data);
        if ($result === FALSE)
        {
            show_error('error !');
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function getUserDetails($id){
        $this->db->select()->from('mh_users')->where('id',$id)->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    public function getUserGallery($id){
        $this->db->select()->from('mh_user_media')->where('user_id',$id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: Bcoz You are using foreach loop for verify/rejected buttons which is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have your "verify" and "rejected" buttons in a foreach loop, they will get duplicated for every user you have. So if you have 10 users, you will have 10 pairs of "verify" and "rejected" buttons.

Simply remove the buttons from the foreach loop to remove the duplicates i.e.

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3" style="margin-left: 344px">
              <a style="text-decoration: none; float: right" href="<?php echo base_url();?>verifyUserEmail/<?php echo $user->email; ?>/<?php echo $user->id; ?>" class="btn btn-link">Verify</a>
              <a style="text-decoration: none; float: right" href="<?php echo base_url();?>rejectedUser/<?php echo $user->email; ?>/<?php echo $user->id; ?>" class="btn btn-link">Rejected</a>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="float: right;">Update</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

To ensure you are passing the correct user information, pass a specific user to the view/form rather than an array/object of users.